# Allowing an arbitrary domain and subdomain in session_store.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there any way to set the `:domain` attribute in `session_store.rb` so that it allows any arbitrary domain and subdomain?

The default settings, which looks like this:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_test-cookie_session', domain: :all
```

allows for arbitrary domain but not subdomain - i.e., it won't work if your application is in, say, `myapp.amazonaws.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`domain: :all` should do exactly what you suspect: allow sharing a cookie across subdomains.

Refer to [here](http://excid3.com/blog/sharing-a-devise-user-session-across-subdomains-with-rails-3/) for pitfalls regarding TLD lengths other than 1.

EDIT:
Here's how you do it:

```
# config/initializers/session_store.rb
DropmyemailV2::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: 'key', domain: :all, tld_length: 3 # myapp.host.com is a tld of length 3
```